# Rails 3 + Tumblr API: How can I edit multiple posts at the same time with one form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-submit, omniauth, tumblr

I'm trying to write a Rails app that fetches a user's Tumblr posts that match certain criteria (for example, only posts that contain certain tags). Once the posts are displayed, I want the user to be able to edit them all at once via one form submit button.

I am authenticating to Tumblr via OmniAuth and making API calls using the tumblr_client gem. See the source code here: https://github.com/monfresh/Fix-my-Tumblr-tags

So far, I've been able to display the correct data, and I am able to edit each post individually. What I don't know how to do is pass in the multiple post IDs as an array, so I can then process them in a loop. Is there a way to do this without creating a new Post model, i.e. without saving the user's posts to my database? Right now, I just have a User model.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out.

In my `form_tag`, I collect the post IDs in an array via checkboxes:

```
<%= check_box_tag "post_ids[]", m["id"] %>
```

and in my controller, I have an action that pulls in those post IDs like so:

```
def edit_tags
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = params[:post_ids]
end
```